Who is doing this input validation for me in the framework
ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API - my controller looks like this:
[HttpGet("teacher/{source}/{id}"]
public async Task<ActionResult<Teacher?>> GetTeacher(TeacherEnumSource source, string id)
{
    var result = await _teacherData.GetTeacher(source, id);
    
    return result == null ? StatusCode(404, $"No Teacher found for Source: {source} and ID: {id}") : Ok(result);
}

Notice the source param is an enum:
public enum TeacherEnumSource
{
    SCHOOL,
    UNIVERSITY,
    KINDERGARTEN
}

If I pass a bad param to my API as source that is not in the enum list, I am automatically getting this error which is kind of nice:
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "source": [
            "The value 'camping' is not valid."
        ]
    },
    "traceId": "00-4e2baa0235572f8359e0e15225fffd3e-4ccac5f22f8ede03-00"
}

If I put breakpoints, it is not even running the _teacherData.GetTeacher(source, id) line so no need to show that code.
I have not added error handling yet and I have even commented out these two lines from my program.cs to make sure:
//app.UseStatusCodePages();
//app.UseExceptionHandler();

So who is doing this error handling for me and more importantly: how can I customize it a bit because I do want to LOG that incident to my external logger (DataDog in my case).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Does this answer your question? How to make "One or more validation errors occurred" raise an exception?

The framework itself handles the validation and the error. It tries to cast the values given as parameter into the type expected by your action, which fails.

Found it myself.  It was the [ApiController] line at top of the class that was doing it

ApiControllerAttribute does a bit more than that (see the docs). And validation is done by the binder AFAIK.

You should choose to use a

Model and use Model validator (post not get)

Manually validate the enum value to test if the value is valid

Validate in your route using a route constraint:
public class RangeConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly int _min;
    private readonly int _max;

    public RangeConstraint(int min, int max)
    {
        _min = min;
        _max = max;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out var value) && int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out int intValue))
        {
            return intValue >= _min && intValue <= _max;
        }
        return false;
    }
}



and integrate it using:
services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("range", typeof(RangeConstraint));
});


Thanks, so approach 2 is not a bad practice? I do need them to be GET . So I had done manual validation in the controller to check if the value is in my enum list , the integer is a real int etc, so that's fine too if I do it that way?

@Bohn, anything that you do that works is good. The simpler the solution the better. ;-)
